# Common issue in all application back image click not proper android devices

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Hello friends i have one back arrow image in top header and when i click on that sometimes i have to press many time in some devices below is my code

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/applogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />
```

in my activity class i call him as

```
        mImageViewAppLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

any idea how can i solve this in one click ? your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: does yout Activity do something in the onDestroy() or onPause or onStop*()?

Comment: Vlad Matvienko: no, nothing do that

Answer (score 0):

It may be your clickable area is very small try to add some padding

```
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:paddingTop="10dip"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
```

Hope that helps !